# How much disk space does Android 2.3.3 and its default apps use?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage

Different phones advertise different total disk space.  When you get a brand new phone with Android 2.3.3 and its default apps, how much disk space do those take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's going to depend on the device. Each carrier/manufacturer likes to add their own apps and widgets. Some even pre-load multimedia files for you. So, this question really can't be answered. (Most definitive answer would be to just get the file sizes of the stock Android ROMs.)

Comment: Is there like a ball park answer? like less than 500 MB or 1 GB?

Comment: @Thierry I've heard anywhere from 80 MB to 400 MB, and wouldn't be surprised if there are bigger ones.  It's quite a range.

Comment: @Matthew Great, that's what I was looking for.  I will assume less than 1GB.

Comment: Great answer to a question I was going to flag as "impossible to answer".